# Did the human lifespan gradually change from 100k to 10k during the course of sata-yuga, or was the change abrupt when treta-yuga began?

Tags: scripture, yuga, human, life-span

Did the human lifespan gradually change from 100 thousands to 10 thousands during the course of satya-yuga, or was the change abrupt when treta-yuga began?

I am only interested in answers that contain precise references to puranas or vedas.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: By common sense you can say it must be continuous

Comment: Hello, what is ka in the title? Is it k?

Comment: I think it would be a gradual thing.